# Calculate cumulative run years/hour based on vehicle performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Condition 1:
if vehicle not failed, calculate cumulative run hours between vehicle start date to today's date.

Condition 2:
if vehicle failed, calculate cumulative run hours between vehicle start date to failed date

**Note:** each vehicle has multiple/single start date and multiple/single/none failed date. so calculate cumulative run hours/years for each vehicle ID

Example SQL table below,

| Vehicle_ID | status | date_on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Start | 2018-05-23 |
| 1 | Start | 2021-06-15 |
| 1 | Failed | 2020-08-10 |
| 2 | Start | 2019-06-23 |
| 3 | Start | 2010-04-20 |
| 3 | Failed | 2010-05-10 |
| 4 | Start | 2011-01-20 |
| 4 | Failed | 2015-01-14 |
| 4 | Start | 2016-02-25 |
| 4 | Failed | 2019-04-10 |
| 5 | Start | 2015-01-14 |
| 5 | Start | 2018-03-16 |
| 6 | Start | 2019-04-10 |
| 6 | Failed | 2020-02-10 |
| 6 | Failed | 2021-04-11 |
| 7 | Start | 2011-01-14 |
| 7 | Start | 2016-03-16 |
| 7 | Start | 2019-04-10 |
| 7 | Failed | 2020-02-10 |

above vehicle ID 1 has 2 start date and 1 failed date, so calculate run years between first start date to first failed date + second start date to till date( no failure happened after second start date).

Vehicle ID 4 has  2 start date 2 failed date, so calculate run years between first start date to first failed date + second start date to second failed date.

I tried following code for calculate run hours between start date to failed date but getting struggle for excluding vehicle ID for below condition.

I am getting result as below format

| VehicleID | Run_years |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.358 |
| 4 | 7.109 |

Above Run years calculated based on below,

**Vehichle Id 1:**

1st **start** to 1st **failed** = 2.21917

2nd **start** to till date(no 2nd failed in vehicle id 1)  = 0.13972

so sum run years      = 2.3589.

**Vehichle Id 4:**

1st **start** to 1st **failed** = 3.986

2nd **start** to 2nd **failed** date  = 3.123

so sum run years      = 7.109.

** Required statement for exclude scenario**

**Vehicle Id 5**

vehicle Id 5 has 2 start date. failed date is missing after 1st start date. so exclude this for run years calculation.

**Vehicle Id 6**

vehicle Id 6 has 2 Failed date and 1 start date. 2nd start date is missing after 1st failed date. so exclude this  for run years calculation.

**Vehicle Id 7**

vehicle Id 7 has 3 Start date and 1 Failed date. 2nd failed date is missing after 2nd start date. so exclude this  for run years calculation.

**Actual logic i required**,  count of **start date** - count of **failed date** is 2 or -1 or -2 then exclude for run years calculation.

**Following codes are I used to calculate run hours without exclude the above condition**

```
select
  s.vehicle_id,
  sum(datediff(day, date_on, isnull(m.min_dt, getdate()))/365.0) run_years
from #samples s
cross apply (
        select min(date_on) min_dt
               from #samples ss
               where s.vehicle_id = ss.vehicle_id
                        and s.date_on < ss.date_on
                        and ss.stat = 'Failed'
) m
where s.stat = 'Start'
group by s.vehicle_id
order by s.vehicle_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a group to each set of "starts" and "fails" by doing a reverse count of fails.  Then aggregate for each "period":

```
select vehicle_id,
       min(case when status = 'start' then date_on end) as start_date,
       coalesce(max(case when status = 'fail' then date_on end),
                getdate()
               ) as end_date,
       datediff(hours,
                min(case when status = 'start' then date_on end) as start_date,
                coalesce(max(case when status = 'fail' then date_on end),
                         getdate()
               ) as diff_hours             
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by vehicle_id order by date_on) as grp

      from t
     ) t
group by vehicle_id, grp;
```

You can then aggregate again, if you want a total per `vehicle`.

Also, this provides the difference in hours.

Comment: @Rock does this answer your question?